# Disable all checkboxes in react-md DataTable

Tags: reactjs, react-md

How can I disable all checkboxes in react-md Datatable component?

I only want to limit the users selected row to 5 and then disable the checkboxes after.
I have been looking at the props of the component at https://react-md.dev/v1/components/data-tables. But can't seem to find a disable prop for checkboxes.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks